# How to get the font color of a certain area in tkinter.Text Widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am actually creating a coding editor and obviously I needed the code to be colored when it appeared on screen. I was successfully able to do that but now, whenever the *already colored* code is edited, the text remains colored. (for example the user writes "print" and it gets colored. Then he erases the 't' from the end of it and it becomes 'prin' and it is still colored) I was hoping there was a way to detect the font color of a tkinter.Text index.
For Example:

```
textArea.get_color("1.0", "1.4"))
# Returns: Black (or whatever color)
```

So the app can change it if it isn't the proper word and still colored. Can Anyone Help Me?

Comment: Could you show some of your code on how you changed the color of specific functions in the first place?

Comment: I used a thread. Inside the thread, my program would split all the text from the text area into lines. It would then seperate each line into words. Then, it'll store every word in a dictionary along side its start and end indexes. Then it would check every word for being a python keyword or python builtin function and if it is either, it would change its color by the index in the dictionary with the word. I can't share the code as it is too long. No modifications to tkinter.Text

Comment: Could you maybe link an image or a github repos to the code? I think it would be helpful in order to answer the code.

Comment: I hope this will be fine: https://pastebin.com/ffStWjqz

Comment: You definitely don't need a thread to get the color of an index.

Comment: ya but I've decided to continuously keep checking every word in the text widget, for that I will need a thread or the thing won't work

Comment: Why do you need to check every word? Why not just check the word at or immediately before the cursor? That seems like overkill to continually check words that aren't changing.

Comment: Great Idea! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can get the color at any text position by first getting the list of tags for that character, and then getting the foreground color of the highest priority tag. If there are no tags with a foreground color, the color is whatever is configured for the text widget.

For example, it might look something like the following:

```
def get_color(index):
    for tag in text.tag_names(index)[::-1]:
        fg = text.tag_cget(tag, "foreground")
        if fg != "":
            return fg
    return text.cget("foreground")
```